# ReactNative - SocketRocket: In debug mode. Allowing connection to any root cert

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to connect my app with Firebase. I made a class that config Firebase:

```js
import Firebase from "firebase";

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
};

let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const db = app.database();
```

And it returns the error of "SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert"
I tried many solutions with include (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/607527c0d4bf6d8197829f3523c4d937ac71ed07) solution but didn't work any of it.
I'm stuck here for the past 2 days and didn't find any workable solution

Comment: In my case, I had to disable the SSL connection. usesSSL == false. you can just try to disable the SSL config according to your config file.

Comment: it means that remote debugging is active but seems firebase settings is not in debug mode.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?